# My Ubuntu dual boot Mac is not recognizing my trackpad, mouse or Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, keyboard, wifi, unix, dual-boot

I dual-booted my Mac laptop with Ubuntu. This worked (after a lot of trying), but it will not recognize the trackpad, keyboard, or Internet.

Under the Bluetooth section, it says "No Bluetooth Found, plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth" if this information helps.
Extra Information: I downloaded Ubuntu with ubiquity -b instead of clicking on the installer since I was getting a grub error.

When I plug in an external keyboard and mouse and use an Ethernet connection through a cable it works though.

What can I do to make it recognize my internal trackpad, keyboard, and Wi-Fi?

Comment: Install a version of Ubuntu that supports the hardware in your laptop.

Comment: @MarcWilson Ok thanks - this might sound stupid, but where can I check that/ find these versions? I am using a MacBook Air 2020 Big Sur with an Intell processor.